# JPA find first by created in given list

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a model class which has these fields:

```java
class Student {
  Long roleNo;
  Long version;
  Date createdAt;
  Date updateAt;
}
```

Now I'm trying to write a JPA query in which I can pass a list of role numbers and for every role number I can get a latest record by version.

I tried to do this but I'm only getting one record:

```java
findFirstByRoleNoIn(List<Long> roleNo);
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to make use of `@Query` annotation to write simple query. Sample query for your case:

```
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = """ 
            SELECT s.* FROM student s
            INNER JOIN (SELECT
              role_no,
              MAX(version) AS latest
            FROM student GROUP BY role_no) t_version
              ON s.role_no = t_version.role_no
              AND s.version = t_version.latest
            WHERE s.role_no IN (:roleNo)
            """)
    findLatestVersion(@Param("roleNo") List<Long> roleNo);
```

Comment: Yeah i have done it with the native query only but i was looking for if there is any way to do it using jpa as well, Though Thanks for the comment.